# Facing Unhandled Exception: Exception: No Internet connection in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, woocommerce

I am new in this flutter and In the woocommerce i have one items and i want to show it in the flutter application  for that i use this library - https://pub.dev/packages/woocommerce/example (with same example). Please let me know what is the issue?? Explain in details so its good to understand me for future purpose. Thank you!!

````
import 'package:woocommerce/woocommerce.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'WooCommerce Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: "Woo Commerce Demo"),
    );
  }
}

String baseUrl = "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/product";
String consumerKey = "ck_a19e3351d476fbfa06a65d79214ed0832815550d";
String consumerSecret = "cs_9624d429661151df9b126b733325bbd714056c9f";


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  List<WooProduct> products = [];
  List<WooProduct> featuredProducts = [];
  WooCommerce wooCommerce = WooCommerce(
    baseUrl: baseUrl,
    consumerKey: consumerKey,
    consumerSecret: consumerSecret,
    isDebug: true,
  );

  getProducts() async{
    products = await wooCommerce.getProducts();
    setState(() {
    });
    print(products.toString());
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //You would want to use a feature builder instead.
    getProducts();

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double itemHeight = (size.height - kToolbarHeight - 24) / 2;
    final double itemWidth = size.width / 2;
    return
      Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Text('My Awesome Shop',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline.apply(color: Colors.blueGrey),
                  ),),
              ),
              SliverGrid(
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight),
                  mainAxisSpacing: 2,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 1,
                ),

                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                      (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    final product = products[index];
                    return
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            height: 230,
                            width: 200,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(product.images[0].src,),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover),
                              color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                            ),
                            //child: Image.network(product.images[0].src, fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                          ),
                          Text(product.name?? 'Loading...', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.apply(color: Colors.blueGrey),),
                          Text('\$'+product.price?? '', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle,)
                        ],
                      );
                  },
                  childCount: products.length,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}```
````

Comment: Why do you think the issue is not sufficiently explained in the error message? "No internet connection" seems pretty plain and understandable? You have no internet connection. You need an internet connection. There is little we can do here, other than to tell you to **get** internet connection.

Comment: I already have an internet connection @nvoigt but still its showing the same issue

Comment: Well, what can I tell you? The code you run on the device you run it on has no internet connection. That is not my personal opinion, that is your error message.

Comment: are you running this in Emulator? i

Comment: I am running in my physical devices @D.R.

Comment: @nvoigt is there any solution for that ??? because i am running this in my physical devices and internet working properly

Comment: If you are running this on a real device, I doubt your "localhost" URL will let you connect anywhere meaningful. Maybe you should find out what needs an internet connection (`NetworkImage` seems a likely candidate), find out where it wants to connect to and see if you can connect there with another app (for example the browser).

Comment: I try to make it with localhost ip address also but its still showing same error (woocommerce website) is working but when i am using same url with flutter , its show this error) @nvoigt

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this in case it helps anyone to debug it faster.

In my case, I was testing on a real device with a pretty decent internet connection. Even after this, I kept on getting the error `Error During Communication: No Internet connection`. The actual problem was that I was trying to call one of the RESTful APIs and its endpoint was dead. I just verified by making a cURL request to the same API endpoint and I got this:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 51.96.4.3 port 1337: Connection refused
```

(51.96.4.3:1337 was my API endpoint). On making the endpoint live again, the error was gone.

IMO, the error message could have been a little less misleading.